# What exactly do dash-to-dock intellihide and intellihide-mode dconf variables do on GNOME 3?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, dconf, gsettings, autohide, dash-to-dock

At least since 18.04 Bionic Beaver, maybe previously, [dash-to-dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1300/ubuntu-dock/) GNOME extension was defined as system default dock application and its settings are stored through `dconf`.

One of those got me confused. The available value description and summary couldn't help me so much, and trying to discover what it does I haven't observed any difference between turn it on or off. So I'm bringing this doubt to here!

What do `org.gnome.shell.extension.dash-to-dock` `intellihide` and `intellihide-mode` dconf variables do?

Comment: Just a pointer, it's not exactly vanilla dash-to-dock that comes with Ubuntu by default nowadays. It's actually a fork of dash-to-dock, called [Ubuntu Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1300/ubuntu-dock/) that is pre-installed and activated as a system extension since Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `intellihide` key dictates whether the dock follows the "intelligent auto-hide mode". That means if you set `intellihide` to true, the dock would always be visible unless it's overlapped by "*a window*".

The `intellihide-mode` defines the "*a window*" part as mentioned before, i.e. it tells the dock which window to dodge. You can set it to avoid *all* windows, or the windows belonging to the *currently focussed* application, or *only maximised* windows.
You can check all possible choices by running the following command:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide-mode
```